# Regex matching all zeroes, first character as zero and remaining characters as numeric

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches cases where an entire value (limited at a length of 10) is comprised of zeroes and cases where the first digit in the series is zero.

I'm trying to filter for cases where a user supplies all zeroes or a leading zero for an input that accepts a maximum of ten digits. At the moment I have the following:

```
(?!0{1,10})[0-9]{1,10}
```

This appears to work, but it does not match non zero values for the first digit in the string. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Edit:

Example failure cases: 0000000, 01234567. Success: 1000000, 2034567 and so forth. I need it to reject cases where the input is all zeroes or leads with a single zero.

Comment: Have you tried using a tester like: https://regex101.com/, it's much easier to test it that way then trying to debug your regex in the program.

Comment: Example failure cases: 0000000, 01234567. Success: 1000000, 2034567 and so forth. I need it to reject cases where the input is all zeroes or leads with a single zero.

Comment: Edit your main post instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first digit can't be a zero:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,9}$
```

Try it in your toaster!